# Getting Camera Info in Cordova

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, camera, cordova-plugins, kendo-mobile

How to get the camera information like megapixels, f 1/3 and other infos using cordova. I'm developing a simple project where the phone's camera must be greater than 5MP. But i don't know how to do it. I couldn't find any plugins too. I'm using cordova 4.2.0 and Kendoui frameworks. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not directly possible with Cordova.

It's mentioned in the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

> Note that information about the camera's resolution is unavailable

You have to write custom plugin in order to use that info for different platforms.

Comment: Thanks @AtanuCSE, well, i'm gonna drop this project, Thanks for the info though :)